# saber directorio de SQLite

Tags: sqlite3

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Android Studio en su ultima version 3.6.3 con acceso a base de datos SQLite,

Para ello en un principio utilice el emulador, y posteriormente tengo conectado mi movil mediante USB, y asi evito tanto consumo de memoria por parte de mi PC.

La cuestion es que quiero ver los datos fisicamente de mi archivo .db de SQLite pero no consigo verlo. Debido a que deseo visualizar si mis datos se guardaron correctamente en mi base de datos.

Existe alguna forma de consultar la bd de datos que tiene el movil almacenado, o bien desde mi disco duro C?

El tipico directorio de una aplicacion es el siguiente pero aqui no lo he visto.

[image: img]

Comment: adentro de app no esta la base de datos?

Comment: He realizado una busqueda de *.db y no ha encontrado nada. No he visto las tablas que se tienen que crear ni los datos añadidos.

Comment: SAlvo que sqlite sea distinto para un celular, en pc es un archivo solo con la extension que quieras.. como se llama la base de datos cuando la abris en tu programa? que cadena de conexion usaste?

Comment: package com.example.aplidb_sqlite;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

Comment: y no le decis donde esta el archivo de datos o algo asi en ningun lado?

Comment: No eso no se hace

Comment: Podrias mostrar como abris o cerras la conexion a tu base de datos? vos decis que en ningun lado configuras eso?

Comment: AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
       
SQLiteDatabase dbAlmacen = admin.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: tu base de datos se llama administracion.. asi sin extension ni nada.. busca ese archivo...

Comment: no lo he encontrado

Comment: en las pruebas que hacias en tu pc tampoco? fijate que el segundo parametro del constructor es el nombre de la base de datos, segun la documentacion...